# Deciding if two lists are cyclic permutations of eachother

Tags: python

I was assigned to write a function that accept two lists and returns True if the other list is a cyclic permutation of the other.
I wrote a function that accepts two lists and changes between the first and the last place. After that i wrote a function that calls the first function using a for loop and returns True at the end of the loop if it was true for each i.
I tries running the code and ive encountered several error messages:

File "C:/WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2Qt5/settings/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 13, in cyclic
    if change_position(lst1, lst2):

File "C:/WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.2Qt5/settings/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 5, in change_position
    lst3[0] = lst4[len(lst4)]

Here is my code:

```
def change_position(lst3, lst4):
    if len(lst3) != len(lst4):
        print(False)
    else:
        lst3[0] = lst4[len(lst4)]


def cyclic(lst1, lst2):
    if len(lst1) != len(lst2):
        print(False)
    else:
        for i in range(len(lst1)):
            if change_position(lst1, lst2):
                print(True)
            else:
                print(False)
cyclic([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1, 2, 3])
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this so the function will work? 
Thanks in advance for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

No need to reorder your list, only index computations will do

```
def is_cyc_perm (list1, list2):
    if len (list1) == len (list2):
        for shift in range (len (list1)):
            for i in range (len (list1)):
                if list1 [i] != list2 [(i + shift) % len (list1)]:
                    break
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


print (is_cyc_perm ([8, 2, 5, 7], [8, 2, 5, 7]))
print (is_cyc_perm ([7, 8, 2, 5], [8, 2, 5, 7]))
print (is_cyc_perm ([2, 5, 7, 8], [8, 2, 5, 7]))
print (is_cyc_perm ([8, 5, 2, 7], [8, 2, 5, 7]))
print (is_cyc_perm ([7, 2, 5, 8], [8, 2, 5, 7]))
print (is_cyc_perm ([8, 2, 5, 3], [8, 2, 5, 7]))
```

Comment: I know your code works, but I'm curious as to why there are "else:" in your code, when there's only 2 "if" statements?

Answer (score 0):

The list index starts with 0, you should use range(0, len(list)-1).

```
def change_position(lst3, lst4):
    if len(lst3) != len(lst4):
        print(False)
    else:
        lst3[0] = lst4[len(lst4)-1]


def cyclic(lst1, lst2):
    if len(lst1) != len(lst2):
        print(False)
    else:
        for i in range(len(lst1)-1):
            if change_position(lst1, lst2):
                print(True)
            else:
                print(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rotating a double linked list is a quick operation with pointers. You can simply try all rotations if there is a match.

The collections module also provides `Counter` which can be used for a quick test if both lists have the same count of the same elements. It is just a stronger version of the obvious same length check.

```
import collections

def is_cyc_perm(seq1, seq2):
    mset1 = collections.Counter(seq1)
    mset2 = collections.Counter(seq2)
    if mset1 != mset2:
        return False

    size = len(seq1)
    deq1 = collections.deque(seq1)
    deq2 = collections.deque(seq2)
    for _ in range(size):
        deq2.rotate()
        if deq1 == deq2:
            return True
    return False
```